# About Ignite Computation Apply Method

Tags: ignite, in-memory-database, gridgain

I have 3 node cluster and I am using ignite computation for parallel operation here I use Apply method.when Execute my job with three node cluster it required 15-20sec and when I run my job with the single node it required 3-5 sec so why it happens.As per Documentation when I use more node it required less time but in my case, it's totally opposite so please can you help me

Comment: Can you add reproducer?

Comment: Hello @EvgeniiZhuravlev, Can you please explain how to add it and it's purpose

Comment: You can add it to github or to dropbox/googledrive and share link with us.
I could check your code and give some recommendations

Comment: hello @EvgeniiZhuravlev Please check my code
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dAS1k4lp1ovBZ9wlLEEjoKTIswHbZ6HYaztXtS0Jt8Q/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Not for all cases a increase count of node brings performance improvement. How you can see it can bring inverse effect. If you tasks/jobs are lightweight then sending them on other nodes can add overhead and it can be significant for this kind of tasks. For execution remote tasks/jobs Apache Ignite serialize them, transportes on remote nodes via TCP/IP. On remote nodes those jobs are deserialize, executed and giving response in the same way (serialize, TCP/IP and etc).

Answer (score 1):

In a case when you access objects from outer class in lambda, these objects will be serialized too, and this behavior gives overhead. As I can see from the code, you don't really need to access any objects out of lambda, you can move all object into the lambda.

Moreover, it will be better creating a static inner class instead of lambda.

Also, I would recommend to warm up JVM and Ignite before any measurements and run more than one iteration.

In Some cases you can use @ComputeTaskNoResultCache annotation, it could give a huge improvement if it fits your case.

I would also recommend reading [this thread on Apache Ignite user list](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Task-management-MapReduce-amp-ForkJoin-performance-penalty-tc16542.html), it contains a few recommendations for improvements of compute grid performance: